# Sanitizing user input being passed to ActiveRecord order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I was wondering the best way to go about sanitizing user input that is being passed to an order query.

I am writing an API for a rails app and would like a user to be able to pass an order_by option to an api request.

For example

```
get :index, :order_by => 'number asc'
```

I've seen using a whitelist as a common solution to limit what actually makes it through to the order call ([gist example](https://gist.github.com/4072943)), but I think I need something more. I would also like to be able to sort on any nested association column as well, like:

```
get :index, :order_by => 'user.last_name asc'
```

How could I achieve this while also preventing any SQL Injection from occurring?